# How to get the resize widget in the bottom right corner of my HTML input tag text box?

Tags: html, input, tags

see the little dots at the bottom right?  how can i get those using an html input tag?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSpW7.png

Comment: Those "dots" are generated by the browser because the textarea is resizable. Are your inputs going to be resizable as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want it or not? You can set the CSS property `resize` to one of these values, but it's not supported by all browsers.

- none
- horizontal
- vertical
- both

Comment: Yes i want it.  so ill have resize="both" as an attribute for my tag?

Comment: Yup, both will allow resize in both directions.